# How to parse QJson file without sorting?

Tags: json, qt

I am parsing a Json file in my Qt application. When I iterate through the QJsonObject keys they are sorted automatically. How can I disable it?

Jsonfile:

```
{
    "General": [{
            "Address": "TODO",
        }
    ],
    "Coordinates": [{
            "Address": "TODO",
        }   
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
for (auto& cat : object.keys()) {
}
```

In the for loop the first object I get is Coordinates, but I want to have in the same order as mentioned in the json file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable it, Qt sorts the keys alphabetically and there is not way to change it.

Comment: What if i use iterator?

Comment: It's the same: the keys are stored alphabetically. If you need a specific order, you may access the keys individually using .value("...") method.

Comment: @vinaycool 
the json is a dictionary, and as the dictionary this is ordered through the key and that is done intentionally, because if we have a json say 1000 elements, do a search (which is the json's task) using the key in a messy container would be very expensive, instead in an orderly container the search has less cost